# How to add timezone to Django GAE project

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, timezone

I'm using GAE Python 2.7 and Django 1.5 for templates. My views currently display datetime in UTC but I would like to display them in local time. I've found other solutions here on stack overflow for how to do this by saving the clients timezone on the server and using Javascript to format date on client, however I would prefer to do this using `{% load tz %}` [Django TZ template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#tz), but it is not being added to my GAE project.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: So have you activated the user's current time zone as shown [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-current-time-zone)?

Comment: According to the docs you have to load time zone by using the {% load tz %} tag. The problem  I'm having is that this tag is not working in gae.

Comment: But as that doc I linked to shows, just loading the tz by itself won't do anything if you haven't told the system what timezone your user is in. You should follow that link and do what it says.